# How to add pydantic field validation for django model?

Tags: django, django-models, pydantic

So, I have a django model, let's say, it's field division is as follows:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    f2 = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

I want to create a pydantic class, with a field type containing list of these models. Consider the following example:

```
class TestPydanticClass(BaseModel):
    model_a_values: List[ModelA]
    f4: int
```

When I am trying to create the `TestPydanticClass` object, but it throws the following error:

```
RuntimeError: no validator found see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

Based upon this, I added `arbitrary_types_allowed` as True, under the `Config` class for the model, and it still throws an error.
Can someone pls suggest a better method of achieving this?

Comment: You do that with a `ForeignKey` from `ModelA` to `TestPydanticClass`, or a `ManyToManyFIeld`, if a `ModelA` can belong to *multiple* `TestPydanticClass`es.

Comment: Why is a MTMField required? TestPydanticClass is a pyddantic model

Comment: It throws the same error or another?

Comment: It is the same error. ```RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'ModelA'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config```

Comment: Strange! I did the same here (set arbitrary_types_allowed = True ) and the error did not appear!

Comment: Not sure. but this worked now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you set this way, inside the BaseModel?

```py
class TestPydanticClass(BaseModel):
    model_a_values: List[ModelA]
    f4: int

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```